# Table colums not the same width?

Tags: html, css, html-table

I'm working on a table with 2 columns that you can see here:  http://www.escalatehosting.com/why-us.php

I can't figure out how to make the two columns the same width though - the right one is a little wider than the left.

This is the style for the table itself:

```
<table align="center" border="0" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="10" style="width:100%">
```

What do I need to change to make the columns the same width?  Does the width need to be a specific amount and not a percentage?

Comment: The question itself should contain sufficient code to reproduce the problem. Currently it shows no attempt at making columnss equal width (or using any columns).

Answer (score 1):

Try adding this CSS rule:

```
td{
  width:50%
}
```

Comment: Good call. ;) +1 for something.

Answer (score 0):

Set each `<td>` to so that it's now `<td style="width: 50%;">`

Answer (score 0):

Rather than putting these boxes in a table why not put them in a div with one box column floated left and the other floated right.....